# Reading HTMLelemend id using C++ WebView2

Tags: c++, windows, webview2

I am working on WebView2 using C++.

Below is part of my HTML.

```
 <div class="container">
        <form id="tenantform" action="about:blank" method="post" data-custom-validation="true" data-enable-shim="true">

            <input id="field_name" type="text" name="field_name" class="form-control">
            <select Id="listvalue" name="listvalue">
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="B">B</option>
            </select>

            <input type="submit" value="Next" />

        </form>
</div>
```

My WebView2 can load about HTMLpage. I could not find any way when the user clicks on submit button how to get `field_name` and `listvalue` values?

Could you please give a pointer for the above problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`CoreWebView2.WebMessageReceived`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2#add_webmessagereceived) to have script in the HTML document post messages to your hosting application. You could add script like the following

https://jsfiddle.net/3uqto6c0/

```js
document.getElementById("submitButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const fieldNameInputValue = document.getElementById("field_name").value;
  const listValue = document.getElementById("listvalue");
  const listValueSelectionValue = listValue.options[listValue.selectedIndex].value;
  
  const result = {fieldNameInputValue, listValueSelectionValue};
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
  if (window?.chrome?.webview) {
    // This will post the message to the WebView2's hosting application.
    // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2#add_webmessagereceived
    window.chrome.webview.postMessage(result);
  } else {
    console.log("Not running in WebView2.");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It is just WebView2 C++ equivalent code of the javascript-based answer.

```
webviewWindow->add_NavigationCompleted(Callback<ICoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventHandler>(
                                [](ICoreWebView2* webview, ICoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs* args) -> HRESULT
                                {
                                    webview->ExecuteScript(L"f = document.getElementById('submitButton');\
                                        f.addEventListener('click', () => {\
                                    const fieldNameInputValue  = document.getElementById('field_name').value;\
                                    const listValue = document.getElementById('listvalue');\
                                    const listValueSelectionValue  = listValue.options[listValue.selectedIndex].value;\
                                    const result = { fieldNameInputValue, listValueSelectionValue  };\
                                    window.chrome.webview.postMessage(result);})"
                                        , Callback<ICoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler>(
                                        [](HRESULT errorCode, LPCWSTR resultObjectAsJson) -> HRESULT
                                        {
                                            return S_OK;
                                        }).Get());
                                    return S_OK;
                                }).Get(), &token);

HRESULT hr = webviewWindow->add_WebMessageReceived(Callback<ICoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventHandler>(
                            [hWnd](ICoreWebView2* webview, ICoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs* args) -> HRESULT {
                                PWSTR message;
                                args->get_WebMessageAsJson(&message);
                                // processMessage(&message);
                                CoTaskMemFree(message);
                                return S_OK;
                            }).Get(), &token);
```

This code is based on MS [sample code](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/tree/master/GettingStartedGuides/Win32_GettingStarted).